# Generalized eigen-decomposition with two constants

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Suppose there are two matrices $\textit{A}, \textit{B}$. Note that $\textit{A}$ is positive-semi definite, $\textit{B}$ is positive definite matrix, both are of size $N\times N$ and symmetric matrix.

If I solve the problem $Ax = \lambda Bx$, then there is a property which is eigendecomposition such that

$$
X^TAX = \Lambda\\
X^TBX = I_N,
$$
where, $\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_N)$ is eigenvalue matrix, the values are on only diagonal elements with descending order, $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_N$, $X$ is eigenvector matrix with the order corresponding $\Lambda$. $I_N$ is $N\times N$ identity matrix.

I would like to know the following derivation is correct.

Assume that I solve the problem

$$
\alpha Ax = \lambda \beta Bx,
$$
where, $\alpha$, $\beta$ are constants except $0$.

I end up with this relationship,

$$
\Big(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}X\Big)^TA\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}X = {\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}\Lambda\\
\Big(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}X\Big)^T B\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}X = I_N.
$$

Can this be correct? If there needs to put all derivations here, I would like to.

Comment: Such decomposition exists for a positive definite $B$ and symmetric $A$, but $X'X \neq I$. In order to find such decomposition you may perform Cholesky decomposition of $B$ first and then reduce this problem to $\tilde{A} x = \lambda I$ with symmetric $\tilde{A}$.

Comment: @PawelKowal Thank you for the comment. I already used Cholesky decomposition when I got the result, and I think I should mention a little more about the matrices, $A,B$ thank you!

Comment: @PawelKowal The eigenvector matrix cannot be the normal matrix generally. You are correct. I updated the information. Thank you!

Comment: Your notation is quite messy. Define $\tilde{B} = (\beta/\alpha) B$, and $\tilde{A} = A$ and consider $\tilde{A}x = \lambda\tilde{B}$. Then your relations are correct, when you replace $A$, $B$ by $\tilde{A}$, $\tilde{B}$.